# query to fetch record without duplication

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

MS-access query : group by name and age, and get the detail without duplicate data(name and age)
please find below the detail

**table schema:**

```
id: integer
name: varchar(100)
age: integer
city: varchar(100)
```

**records in table:**

```
------------------------------------
id| name    | age | city
------------------------------------
1 | ram     | 25 | bhopal
2 | brajesh | 30 | indore
3 | ram     | 25 | indore
4 | ram     | 26 | bhopal
5 | ram     | 27 | mumbai
6 | brajesh | 30 | mumbai
7 | brajesh | 26 | dehli
------------------------------------
```

**Expected result :**

```
------------------------------------
name    | age | city | city
------------------------------------
ram     | 25 | bhopal | indore
brajesh | 30 | indore | mumbai
------------------------------------
```

**Other format of Expected output :**

**Expected result :**

```
------------------------------------
name    | age | city
------------------------------------
ram     | 25 | bhopal, indore
brajesh | 30 | indore, mumbai
------------------------------------
```

Comment: This looks like a distinct cross-tab query. The way it's done by ACCESS and MYSQL are different. So first decide which way you want it. If you're using ACCESS, I recall there used to be a thing called *pivot table* which may help. Often the Wzard takes care of the technical stuff.

Comment: hey, I have edited the question, and now there are two format of expected result, and yes I want query for ms-access

Comment: how do you want to use result of desired query?

Comment: You have multiple data rows for each person, yet only one result row for them, so the first question is: how do you want to pick values such as age?  You chose whichever row has the lowest ID value, but is that too arbitrary?  In your example, this gives the lowest age.  But what if someone adds a row (8, ram, 22, jaipur)?  Which age should you really show now?  Should it be min(age), max(age), both, or avg(age)?  Or perhaps you want current age, introduces a new issue. Which cities should you show? Your design only shows two, but do you want it to be arbitrary which ones you show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick :

```
select distinct d1.name, d1.age, concat(d1.city, ' , ' ,d2.city) AS city  from
Details d1 join Details d2
on d1.name = d2.name
and d1.age = d2.age
and d1.city != d2.city
and d1.id < d2.id
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70cee/24)

Also note that for this to work *id must be unique*.

Comment: This won't work if the same (name, age) combination is in more than two cities. The closest I can come right now to working with an arbitrary number of cities is with the PostgreSQL `string_agg` function, as at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/70cee/2/0

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is impossible to get first output by query, due to need spawning columns for every distinct city.

This is how to get second variant in ms-access, but it is not optimal: 
define sfunction

```
public function SitiesOf(Name as String,Age as long) as String
    dim rst as recordset
    SitiesOf = ", "
    set rst = currentdb.Openrecordset("SELECT [city] FROM [Table] WHERE [name]='" & Name & "' AND [age]=" & Age & ";")
    while not rs.eof
        SitiesOf = SitiesOf & rst![city] & ", "
        rst.MoveNext
    wend
    rst.close
    set rst=Nothing
    SitiesOf = left(SitiesOf , len(SitiesOf)-2)
end function
```

Write query

```
SELECT [name] , [age] , SitiesOf([name],[age]) FROM [Table] GROUP BY [name] , [age]
```

Comment: Could have been a comment.

Comment: sorry, i have not much experience. So i decided to put it to answer due to question have to be totally changed to have another answer

Comment: hey, I have edited the question, and now there are two format of expected result, take a look, thanks

Comment: Can you please explain me what is `SitiesOf` in your query ?

Comment: Previously written function which collects cities for a given [name] and [age], you should to put it in some module in your ms-access db.